# Fetch all data (including image) from a webpage in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to know is this possible that we can load all of the data from a webpage using asp.net. Like I have a page including a table and a pie-chart. I am exporting my html content to pdf on my button click. I have used hidden field to fetch the `innerHTML` data to transform on server-side. I am getting the data but the problem is ,when I do export to pdf the piechart is nowhere to be seen.
C# code  :

```
string htmlstring =  hiddenTest.Value;
 pdfConverter.SavePdfFromHtmlStringToFile(htmlstring, downloadName);
```

HTML :

```
    function DrawPieChart(series) {

                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                        plotShadow: false,
                        backgroundColor: {
                            linearGradient: [50, 0, 100, 500],
                            stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                        [1, 'rgb(0, 00, 0)']
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Matched and Unmatched Regions'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Percentage',
                        data: series
                    }]
                });





            }

            function htmlbind() {
                debugger;
                var d = document.getElementById('pdfdiv');
                var e = document.getElementById('hiddenTest');
                e.value = d.innerHTML;
            }



        </script>
        <%--<My:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" UserName="a" UserAge="45" UserCountry="Australia" />--%>
        <%--<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phUserInfoBox" />--%>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#999999">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="button" Text="click" runat="server" OnClick="b1_click" OnClientClick="htmlbind();"/>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" Text="click" runat="server" OnClick="b2_click" />
                <div>

                </div>
 <div id="pdfdiv" runat="server">
            <div id="container">
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFilePath" runat="server" OnValueChanged="hfFilePath_ValueChanged" />

            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hiddenTest" />
```

javascript :

```
function htmlbind() {
            debugger;
            var d = document.getElementById('pdfdiv');
            var e = document.getElementById('hiddenTest');
            e.value = d.innerHTML;
        }
```

Hopes for suggestion.

Comment: What is the `src` attribute of the pie chart image?

Comment: @ErikS - this question is not a duplicate. The likely problem here is that `pdfConverter` opens a new session of the OP's web app, which may require authentication and/or `Session` variables for any browser-server interaction.

Comment: Ok I misread the question.

Comment: You would need to convert the chart client side to image using canvas, or use alternate server side image charting script for pdf

Comment: Can u plz guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: Actually it might already be canvas or svg. Do some web searching on how to upload or convert

Comment: I am a little confuse on what u want to do here, like on client side the chart will be converted to canvas and send to server-side for exportation. Is that so?

Comment: what is `series` in `DrawPieChart(series)` and how do you call it?

Comment: its being set below as how the series will be . Like 1 series or 2 series defining the combination of the chart

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pure HTML/Javascript example, but it also applicable for your case with a few adaptations.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucasdamiani/skrhd982/16/ (I won't put the code here because there is a bunch of HTML and Javascript)

You can use this function from the script:

```
saveSvgAsPng(el, options)
```

el is the svg element, and options can be null.

In this example I get the chart generated by highcharts and transform it as pure HTML, transforming the SVG image in a data URI.

See http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/ for the detailed logic to converted the graphic into PNG.

Comment: Can't it be possible that all the html data could convert one time. ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean by "html data could convert one time". Could you please clarify the statement?

Comment: I mean to say if the other data is being imported, then why not the piechart data

Comment: As I can see, the chart is a SVG tag and not an image. You're also using highcharts, that has a built in function to export to PDF. You can take a look at this piece of code http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-exportchart-filename/. It will export the chart to a PDF without your server side logic.

Comment: but the issue here is that i have to make 1 pdf holding all my data (including the image)